# ActivityGroup for Buttons without tabActivity

Tags: android

I am new to this topic, i want to implement Activity group for buttons without tabs. I am using Eclipse. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: we use tabactivity but i want to use with out tab activity

Comment: i want to show buttons like tab buttons but not tabs and when i click on 1st button it will show 1st screen and when i will click on 2nd button it will show 2nd screen but positions of buttons remain same like in tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always achieve that goal by creating two separate classes and using 1 layouts.

example:

class A

Button 2 calls main layout and class B

class B

Button 1 calls main layout and class A

This isn't Official but it will do the job, I use this method all the time and it works like a charm.

Comment: i am trying this but did not get you can give me link where i can see your code how you do?

Comment: your xml layout  LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout

Comment: ..class A                                                                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.maina);
  
  Button bMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.);buttona
  bMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         
   startActivity(new Intent("com.xxx..MESSAGE"));
         
    }
   });

Comment: ..class B                                                                                                                                        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.maina);
  
  Button bVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.);buttonb
  bMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         
   startActivity(new Intent("com.xxx..VIDEO"));
         
    }
   });

Comment: You should know where all of this starts and ends at ... Hope that helps.